# how to remove '/' slash from folder name inside repository in github?

Tags: git, github

I am adding a file inside a folder's folder. after adding the file, when I see the repository, it is showing me a **slash**. how to remove that?

[how to remove / slash from folder name ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g5Cu.png)

Comment: github does this automatically when a folder has only one element. It's a super useful feature. The folder name doesn't actually contain a `/`.

Comment: @mousetail, If I add more files to the folder, then the / will be removed.?

Comment: If you add it to the parent folder yes

Comment: @mousetail If u see the image attached above, I have only one folder inside food i.e., fruits, and inside it is a .doc file. If I add another folder named 'vegetables' inside the food folder, then the / is removed automatically. I think what u have told that more than one element, / is removed.

Answer (score 2):

That slash isn't anything. The github is just specifying where the update happened. If you look closely you can see that "Food/" is grey while "Fruit" is black.

TL;DR : there's nothing to remove

Comment: I saw that. But I have a problem with '/' in the repository.

Comment: If you have an error do you mind sharing? because that "/" isn't in the name.
that slash is just  to divide the 2 folders names.  It's only visual

Comment: Thanks I got it from the above comments. doubt resolved

Answer (score 1):

The slash is an illusion.  In fact, folders in general in Git are an illusion.  Git doesn't store folders in the first place.<sup>1</sup>  What Git stores are *commits*, and what commits store are *files and metadata*.

Files, in Git, have long names that contain embedded (forward) slashes, such as `classes/science.ext`, `food/fruits/apple.ext`, and `new/welcome.png`.  If you check out a commit that has these three files in it and run:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

you'll see output like this:

```
100644 8f3f967230c9ec9a6386b37700891e0f648dc93f 0       classes/science.ext
100644 93df50769a3921e771b714fa1c9ee83f5483f016 0       food/fruits/apple.ext
100644 cc46fc918955220eea72d2fa5839909a41000712 0       new/welcome.png
```

(the hash IDs in column 2 will be different; I stole these hash IDs from a few files I had nearby).

This is what's in Git.  Of course, for you to be able to *work with* these files—the ones inside Git are frozen: completely read-only, compressed, readable only by Git and writable by *nothing*, not even Git itself, once they've been frozen into place like this—Git has to *copy* those files *out* of the commit, into a work area.  This work area lives on your computer ("your laptop", or a server, or whatever), in the usual format that your OS uses to *store* files, which is probably folder-structured.  So when you clone a repository and *extract* a commit, you do get files-in-folders.

When GitHub or some other server site lets you *browse through* commits, they must fix up this mismatch: Git stores *files* with embedded forward slashes in their names, but what the *user wants to see* is a set of folders containing files.  So GitHub do the same thing Git does: dynamically *pretend* that there are folders containing sub-folders containing files, and so on.

When GitHub discover a "folder" that contains just one "sub-folder", Git*Hub*—not Git—choose to *display* that as `food/fruits`.  That's not what's in the commit: the commit contains *files* named `food/fruits/apple.ext` or whatever.  But rather than showing you a synthesized folder named `food` that, if you clicked on it, would next show you a synthesized folder named `fruits` that, if you clicked on it, would next show you the file `apple.ext`, GitHub choose to reduce the number of mouse-clicks required, by showing you a synthetic folder whose name is `food/fruits`.

Since this folded doesn't really exist anywhere—Git has to *create* `food` and `food/fruits` later, at the time you `git checkout` or `git switch` to the commit that contains the file `food/fruits/apple.ext`, so that your laptop is happy creating a file named `apple.ext` in a folder named `fruits` in a folder named `food`—it doesn't matter how the display works.  All that matters is that you know that Git stores *commits* that then store *files*.

The GitHub display deliberately "peeks through" various commits to find which file(s) were most recently changed-or-added within some synthesized "folder" and puts that at the far right, giving you a display:

```
  classes        science file added            6 hours ago
  food/fruits    apple file added            2 minutes ago
```

and the like.  That's not the result of any *one* commit, that's the result of poking around in *many* commits in the repository, finding one from 2 minutes ago and a different one from 6 hours ago and pasting together different pieces of information from the two different commits.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it's the *index* that doesn't store folders.  When Git stores files inside a commit, it uses a tree of subtrees-and-files that very strongly resembles the way a typical file system stores folders-and-files.  Had Git's index allowed directory entries to exist, Git would be able to store folders.  But Git's index *doesn't* allow for directory structure—it's a flattened tree of nothing-but-files—and Git builds commits from the index.  Thus, Git doesn't let you store an *empty* folder; all folders are always implied.

<sup>2</sup>To avoid pasting information together like this, select a different "view".  For instance, if you [click on a particular commit hash ID](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376), then click on [browse files](https://github.com/git/git/tree/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376), you get a view of what's in that commit.  They still do their trick of figuring out files that were recently modified and when by looking at earlier commits, but if you click on [one particular file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d420dda0576340909c3faff364cfbd1485f70376/GIT-VERSION-GEN), you get the version of that file that goes with that one particular commit.